# How to access :: operator of template types in C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am using a C++ library (Apache arrow) that has it own types (i.e. `arrow::Int64Type`) and each type has its an equivalent c_type that is access by using `Type::ctype`. For example

`arrow::Int64Type::ctype x`; is equivalent to `int x;`

I am using the arrow type as a template parameter and I would like to define a member variable of the `ctype` associated with the arrow type. Something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct S {
    T member_of_arrow_type;
    T::ctype member_of_c_type; // this does not work
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(member_of_c_type).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main
{
  S<arrow::Int64Type> x;
  x.foo(); // this should print "int"

  S<arrow::DoubleType> x;
  x.foo(); // this should print "double"
}
```

Is it possible to do it in C++17?

Comment: The template type is arrow::Int64Type or arrow::DoubleType and I would like to get c equivalent of that i.e. int and double

Comment: Add `typename` before `T::ctype`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names

Comment: It worked!! thanks.